# What type of timestamp does "gcloud compute instances list" produce

Tags: timestamp, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When you output gcloud compute instances list as json, the timestamps look like this:

```
2016-05-22T12:22:29.285-07:00
```

But I can't find an explanation of the format in the documentation. I would interpret it as:

```
YYYY-MM-DDT<hours>:<minutes>:<seconds>.<fraction>-<timezone>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there's a documented guarantee on how the timestamps are emitted but this appears to be [RFC3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) with fractional seconds. Your interpretation is basically correct except that:

- YYYY-MM-DD-T is actually YYYY-MM-DDT, a simple typo I'm sure
- -<timezone> is actually +/- time offset from UTC